# I have created an Azure image out of a VM which has two NICs. when I created a new VM using image I am was able to see only one NIC in new VM

Tags: azure, image, cloud, virtual-machine, nic

I have created an Azure image out of a VM which has two NICs. when I tried to create a new VM using image I was able to see only one NIC - is this a limitation? how to over come the situation

Answer (score 0):

The image covers only the VM's disk contents, so the nic isn't part of the image. It's part of the VM definition.

What you did is a bit like copying the contents of your laptop's disk to a different laptop, and expecting the other's laptop hardware to change as a result.

Comment: Malt is there way to overcome the usecase?

Comment: Use the Azure ARM API to create a VM with two NICs - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/linux/quick-create-template

Comment: I tired ARM template before checking your response and it worked. any ways a Big Thank you to you Malt.